# HTTPS request containing BASE64 encoded string as parameter working fine from POSTMAN but not from java code even though it is URL encoded

Tags: java, base64, http-post, url-parameters

I need to POST a request containing BASE64 encoded string as parameter. When I am trying from POSTMAN , it is working fine but from the java code , it is not working. My Java code is as follows:

```
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        conn.setReadTimeout(timeoutVal);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(timeoutVal);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();


        String reqParam = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString((<Test>Value</Test>).getBytes());

        postParams.put("param1", reqParam);
        postParams.put("param2", "A");


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {


            response="";

        }

private static String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(),"UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(),"UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

The code works fine if there is no Base64 encoded parameter.

Please help!!!

Comment: Any pointers???